# redux-saga cannot catch actions dispatched by store enhancers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I need to use store enhancer (reactReduxFirebase from [react-redux-firebase](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase)) in my redux app. This enhancer dispatches an action, it looks more or less like this (much simplified):

```js
const reactReduxFirebase = (next) => {
  return (reducer, initialState, middleware) => {
    const store = next(reducer, initialState, middleware);
    store.dispatch({
      type: 'DUMMY_ACTION'
    });
    return store;
  }
}

// usage
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const middleware = [sagaMiddleware];
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    reactReduxFirebase
  )
);
sagaMiddleware.run(sagas);

// sagas.js
function* handle(action) {
  console.log(action);
}

function* saga() {
  yield takeEvery('*', handle);
}

export default saga;
```

I want saga to listen to all actions and console.log them, but it doesn't catch 'DUMMY_ACTION' dispatched by enhancer, because it's being dispatched before saga starts to listen (`sagaMiddleware.run(sagas);`). From redux-saga docs it seems that saga must be run after applyMiddleware, so I cannot make saga run before enhancer. Is there any way to make it work, so the saga will catch an action from enhancer as well?

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order of the arguments of compose. That way firebase will be passed the saga-enhanced createStore which may fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution based on `applyMiddlware`:

```js
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import { takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import {
  reducer
} from '../reducers';

function sagaPreinitMiddleware(saga) {
  return (createStore) => (reducer, preloadedState, enhancer) => {
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

    const store = createStore(reducer, preloadedState, enhancer);
    let dispatch = store.dispatch;
    const middlewareAPI = {
      getState: store.getState,
      dispatch: (action) => dispatch(action)
    };
    dispatch = compose(sagaMiddleware(middlewareAPI))(store.dispatch);
    sagaMiddleware.run(saga); // run the saga
    return {
      ...store,
      dispatch
    };
  };
}

const reactReduxFirebase = (next) => {
  return (reducer, initialState, middleware) => {
    const store = next(reducer, initialState, middleware);
    store.dispatch({
      type: 'DUMMY_ACTION'
    });
    setTimeout(store.dispatch({
      type: 'DUMMY_ACTION_1'
    }), 100);
    return store;
  };
};

// usage
const middleware = [];
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  0,
  compose(
    reactReduxFirebase,
    sagaPreinitMiddleware(sagas)
  )
);


// sagas.js
function* handle(action) {
  console.log(action);
}

function* sagas() {
  yield takeEvery('*', handle);
}
```

The log:

```js
   00000000: [reducer] action Object {type: "@@redux/INIT"}
   00000008: [reducer] action Object {type: "DUMMY_ACTION"}
             Object {type: "DUMMY_ACTION"}
   00000011: [reducer] action Object {type: "DUMMY_ACTION_1"}
             Object {type: "DUMMY_ACTION_1"}
```

Comment: Very interesting. How exactly does it work though?

Comment: I finally tried this and it doesn't appear to work. If I'm mistaken, could you explain how it's intended to work @DraganS?

Answer (score 0):

try this for sagas

```
function* log(action) {
  while (true) {
    yield take('*');
    console.log(action);
  }
}

export default function* root() {
  yield all([call(log)]);
}
```

just to see if it works then you can try moving to takeEvery, I did have issues with it and creating handles specific to saga worked